# Field rules in Search Scope is not working with tags field of my pages

Tags: sxa, content-search

I am using SXA Sitecore 9.3, my requirement is to get search result based on SXA tags on the pages, for which I have applied query and rule in search scope. But the tag result is not accurate, even after doing indexing several times. The pages that don't have the tag "Energy Management" also come up in the search result.

This is my search scope

[image]

This is my main page to show the result based on this field value

[image: Page on which the search result need to be displayed]

Any suggestion or other approach is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is your exact requirement? As you are using the tags for boosting and not scoping it is possible to have results that do not match the boost rule.

Comment: @Gatogordo My requirement is to have a search result based on the field value in my current page, which is "Energy management" here, and the page template in search query which is having this "Energy Management" as tag selected under tagging section should appear in search result.

Comment: As @Gatogordo has written, boosting will not scope the results. It will just try to boost certain results (put them at first).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the results of your search, you need to use the scope and not the boost as that will not limit (just boost). So you need to add the tag requirement to the scope where you now only have the template.

You might be able to use the out-of-the-box SXA tokens in the search scope to match your needs. Check out the documentation here: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/extend-search.html#UUID-3cbc7b12-9aed-f7d2-cd98-fcca239042ee_id__Extend_data_source_body

If the oob stuff doesn't get you what you need, you can always extend the tokens with a custom one. You can check out my blog to see how that can be done: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/01/extending-sxa-search-query-tokens.html This way you can really match the scope to anything you like.